# Sqlite - how to order by a column with empty spaces?

Tags: android, sqlite, spaces, sql-order-by

I have a column table with first name and last name (separated by spaces) in my android application. I need to sort by this column to show it in a listview. I'm using rawquery to do this.

Comment: how to order by a column with empty spaces?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of query:

```
SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY LOWER(yourFieldName);
```

You can also do `ORDER BY yourFieldName COLLATE NOCASE`.

Edit: If you need to specify `ASC` or `DESC`, add this after `NOCASE`